# graph using 2 sets of data which each one with it's own threshold

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

In HighCharts Line Chart, how do I set the colour of a series line depending on its value in relation to the value of a threshold.

see below picture to understand my need.
[image]

I am trying to figure out how to create a line graph using 2 sets of data which are stored in a json object.And each set have its own threshold.

```
<pre><code>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [
    {
        data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
        threshold: 5,
        negativeColor: 'green',
        color: 'red',
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        },
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            color: '#f7a35c'
        }, {
            value: 10,
            color: '#7cb5ec'
        }, {
            color: '#90ed7d'
        }]
    },
    {
        data: [-9, -6, 1, 6, 11, 16, 11, 11, 6, 1, -4],
        threshold: 10,
        negativeColor: 'red',
        zones: [{
            value: 5,
            color: 'cyan'
        }, {
            value: 12,
            color: 'magenta'
        }, {
            color: 'green'
        }]
    }]
});
</pre></code>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API option, so you can vote for this feature request here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13986

As a workaround, you can use the following code, where the new zone array is created based on the provided threshold.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        function checkRange(number, rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
          if (number >= rangeStart && number <= rangeEnd) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }

        let chart = this;
        chart.series.forEach(series => {
          let newZones = [];

          for (let i = 0; i < series.zones.length; i++) {

            if (checkRange(series.zones[i].value, -Infinity, series.options.threshold)) {
              newZones.push({
                value: series.options.threshold,
                color: series.options.negativeColor
              }, {
                value: series.zones[i + 1].value,
                color: series.zones[i].color
              })
            } else {
              newZones.push({
                value: series.zones[i].value,
                color: series.zones[i].color
              })
            }
          }
          series.update({
            zones: newZones
          }, false)
        })

        chart.redraw()
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1nrta4vu/